# same base url with different functionalities nodejs

Tags: node.js

```
    app.get('/api/v3/app/events', async function (req, res){
            try {
                let unique_id=req.query.id
                console.log(unique_id)
              
                 database.collection('event').findOne(ObjectId(unique_id),function(err,data){
                    if(err){
                        res.json({error:"no data found with specified id"})
                    }
                    console.log(data)
                    res.json(data)}
                )
              
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("internal error")
                res.json({error:error})
            }
    
        })
    
    
    
     app.get('/api/v3/app/events', function(req,res) {
            try {
                let limit=parseInt(req.query.limit)
                let page =parseInt(req.query.page)
                console.log(database.collection('event').find().sort({$natural: -1}).limit(limit).skip(page-1).toArray((err, result) => {
                    console.log(result);
                })
                )
                
                
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
                return res.json({error:"internal error "})
            }
            
        })
```

I have to perform these functionalities with same base url i.e '/api/v3/app/events'.
Please help . I am successful as I change the names of endpoints, but keeping them same , I gets null and undefined on the console

Comment: Deal with both sets of valid query parameters in the same function? But probably the first one should actually be `/events/:id`.

Comment: there are multiple ways to deal with this. you can create endpoints or you can use something like if else or switch to handle each functionality. Even if you create endpoints you will be using the same base url, so its valid, and arguably the right way to do so.

Comment: If I give you an address and ask you to go there, would you arrive at 2 different places? That's what is happening with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why do you need both to use same URL, but you have two choices either use a single endpoint with both of the logics. The other option would be to use the next middleware based on the `id` query param like this:

```
app.get('/api/v3/app/events', async function (req, res, next){
    if (!req.query.id) {
        next();
        return;
    }

    // Rest of your endpoint logic
}
```

Each endpoint in Express is considered as middleware. This means that response won't be sent back, but calling the `next()` middleware instead and allow other middlewares to be executed. You can use same `if` or modify it based on your login.

Comment: this is working fine and giving the desired output as a response but giving bunch of errors in the console for "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client", that means both the requests are being handled at a same time, any suggestions to overcome them

Comment: My bad, It's because the function doesn't return after calling the `next()` middleware. So, it tries to send back another response while response already sent. My answer updated to fix that

Comment: thank you very much, btw what is return doing, what does it returns

Comment: It returns nothing, it's just to stop executing the rest of endpoint function. The other options would be to use an `if` then `else` for the rest of logic, but the return looks cleaner